# Java Operating System to .ISO

Tags: java, operating-system, iso

Alright, so for the past while I've been working on an Operating System style Java application. I've got everything loaded up within an undecorated JFrame, and now I'm ready to turn it into a .ISO or something along those lines. My question, is how would I do this? I've seen articles online saying yes, you can have a Java Operating System, and I've seen examples of some, but I'd like to know HOW. Like if I were to load it into some sort of Virtual Machine, I'd like to do what I've programmed it to do.

Comment: An .ISO is just a disk image.  When you extract it, you get an actual disk.  There are [a number of utilities](https://www.google.com/#q=utilities+that+create+.iso+files) that are capable of making .ISO's.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Alright, so do you know a way to make the Disk Image run?

Comment: Your user has to extract it to an actual disk.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I do know how to make an ISO, I guess I just meant how to make the Disk Image itself. Sorry for unclarity.

Comment: With an .ISO utility.  You supply the original disk as the source.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I still don't think that's what I was looking for. I just want a way to take my .jar, and turn it into the image that when loaded by a computer, or some sort of Virtual Machine, it would run as the operating system. For example, Virtual Box. If you download the Linux Ubuntu .ISO file, you can load it into that, and run the OS. I'd like to know how to make my file work like that. Where I can just load it, and run it as the OS itself.

Comment: Creating ISO's is not a programming problem.  There a existing tools to do this.  (Besides, an ISO is probably the wrong way to distribute an application.)

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I realize that I phrased my question incorrectly. I meant to say how to create the file that when loaded by a VM will run the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to run your code as the operating system of a virtual machine, then an ISO is a good choice.

There are existing tools for generating ISO's ... provided you have the "stuff" to go into the ISO.

Your problem is generating the stuff that goes into the ISO; i.e. a bootable operating system image.  The problem is that the image must be all native code, and it needs to understand all the low level stuff about how the hardware works; e.g. how to deal with physical / virtual memory mapping, I/O device registers, hardware interrupts, and so on.  So you have the problems of implementing the classes (or native code) that does that, and compiling your Java classes into native code and linking it together with everything else to form a bootable operating system image.  (And that is just the start ... really)

For those things, there are no existing tools (AFAIK), and little in the way of experience to draw on.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. But do you know any resources that I could use to get started on that? Any webpages, books, or lectures I could use to learn to do this? Or should I just go back to C++ where I started?

Comment: You need to learn about the native instruction set, get and read the manuals for the hardware devices on your computer, read good books on how to implement a native code generator, read about the JVM and how it works.  How many man-years do you have to complete this project????

Comment: Well, considering I'm only 14, I've got quite a bit of time.

Comment: *"Or should I just go back to C++ where I started?"* -  If your aim is to get something running on a bare machine / virtual ... then YES, that is a much simpler way of doing it.

Comment: An acquaintance of mine also recommended I use assembly, though I have no experience with it. Would that be of any benefit?

Comment: I didn't say years.  I said manyears ... assuming that you are working on the project full time, 7.5 hours a day 5 days a week, 50 weeks a year.  I'd estimate that it is a couple of manyears for a seasoned low-level developer / compiler writer to get to a barely functioning system written in Java.  Much longer if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Assembly language is too level to write a decent OS.  Takes too long.  C or C++ would be ideal.  The advantage of C / C++ is that there are "kits" out there for doing this, so you don't have to do all of the nitty-gritty low-level stuff yourself.